# How to do contract work for previous employer?

Tags: contracts, germany, legal, freelancing

I'll be switching jobs soon, because I'll be moving to another city.

If the need arises, I'd like to do some consulting work for my current employer (remotely).

I would be limiting this to a few hours per month maximum, so that it doesn't interfere with my future job, and my current employer is willing to pay those hours.

Assuming the future employer has no objections, what would be a reasonable way to set up a contract in this situation?

This question is about Germany.

If I simply declare this to be freelance work, apparently there is a risk that the tax office will consider it de-facto permanent employment (due to the previous employment contract), and demand social insurance payments etc.

To satisfy tax regulations, it seems that a new employment contract would be required. However, it is my understanding that zero-hour ("on demand") contracts are not legally possible in Germany, either.

If this is correct, is there any alternative?

Comment: `Assuming the future employer has no objections` well, this is actually the hardest part. Very rare a employer will allow employee to do salaried contract work in same field for a different company or even competitor.

Comment: "I would be limiting this to a few hours per month maximum, so that it doesn't interfere with my future job"  Working extra hours each month will affect you both physically and mentally, it WILL interfere with your new job.

Comment: @tweray The companies are no competitors, otherwise I wouldn't be thinking about it. It is my understanding that legally, a side job is usually not a problem as long as it doesn't interfere with one's ability to handle their main job.

Comment: @sf02 I'm aware of the problems this could cause, that's why I'm looking for something like a zero-hour contract that would allow me to limit the hours to a level I'm sure I can handle at the given time.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere If you're sure about this, I would appreciate it if you'd turn your comment into an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: How much do you expect to work for them?  In many countries there is a legal limit below which you do not need to be a registered business in order to work a few hours

Comment: @GeorgeM As stated in the OP, it would be no more than a few hours per month, but there would be no fixed number of hours. If there is a legal limit, I could try to keep the hours below the limit. I'm not aware that there is such a limit in Germany, though.

Comment: Then @tmh, you should ask :-)

Answer (score 3):

**I know everyone loves the phrase "HR is not your friend" - but in this case, it's at least your ally.**

Your old company wants you as a contractor.  You want to contract for them.  HR is the piece designed to make sure all the red tape with that arrangement is nicely handled.  This is one of the beautiful times where everyone wants the same resolution to the situation.  So just ask HR at the prior company what are the ways that this could be handled/structured, and then go from there.

*Just make sure you take care of the biggest potential problem: the new employer.  Make sure they're okay with your proposed auxiliary work.*

Comment: Good answer. I must say, and without wanting to sound too loom, that it's very likely the new company will not like the idea of OP working for the old company. Even less if they are on the same industry, chances are this will conflict with whatever NDA or non-compete agreement OP has to sign in the future job... but, like you say, HR is a good way to start this process